# Resize partition without affecting other OSes in dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I wanted to resize (increase or decrease the partition size) the existing Ubuntu partition without affecting it and the other OS(es) installed in the machine.

Comment: Resize in what manner?  Increase size of partition?  Decrease size?  If you want to increase, did you resize the other OS' partitions to make free space for the system to expand the Ubuntu partition onto?

Comment: wanted to increase partition size; the other os has got some more unused memory space;

Comment: You can use "largest continous space"

Comment: @user7044 by "unused memory space" what do you mean?  Free space on the partition?  Unallocated drive space on the drive itself (i.e. not partitioned)?  If you mean the first (free space on the partition), you'd still need to resize that partition in order to be able to free up that unused space on the partition so the other partition you're expanding can use it.

Comment: @alexy13 They already have Ubuntu installed, so selecting "largest continuous space" won't help.

Comment: I meant free space on the partition,

Comment: @user7044 please include the output of sudo parted -l. So we can advise you on your actual set up.

Comment: could you post informations about the disk? partitions and sizes?

Answer (score 6):

You can resize a Windows (NTFS) partition from Ubuntu using GParted. You'll need to shrink the partition to free up some unallocated space on the drive. Then you will be able to create a new Linux partition in that space.

GParted is not installed by default, look for it in the Software Center or install it in therminal by doing

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

It won't be possible to modify your Ubuntu root partition (or, more precisely, any partition which is in use) while booted in Ubuntu. To do this, boot from Ubuntu Live CD and run GParted from there.

Make sure you have a backup of your important data before proceeding because it's a potentially dangerous operation.

You can find more documentation on GParted here: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Will it be less dangerous if the two OS's are installed in separate drives, while the PC is still in dual boot mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can re-size partitions, provided they are not in use mounted when you do so.

It will probably be easier to do this after booting up using a live disk. Not into your installed system.

As this is risky you should make sure you have a back up before you begin. I lost a whole system due to a power out-age do this. You have no excuses for not having back ups if some thing goes wrong.

You may need to install additional file systems tools such as ntfs-tools if you want to re-size partitions other then ext2/3/4.

Lots of good documentation on using Gparted can be found here.
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/documentation.php

With this document giving you step for step instructions on how to re-size a partition. With nice screen shots.
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/resize/resizing.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's a very generic question so I'll do some assumptions and write a generic answer. Usually if I have to do such things and the other operating system is windows I do the following. In windows disable hybernation and fast boot (depends by the windows version). Use defrag 2 times and fully defrag every disk windows can see. Write on your phone the amount of space you have available in windows and the amount of ram on that machine. Then produce a live usb with Gparted live. Reboot windows and boot the gparted live usb. Decrease size of the windows partition but leave at least twice the size of the ram on that partition (just to be sure). Increase the size of linux partition you want to increase. Commit your changes and reboot. Boot linux and check if everything works. Boot Windows and check if everything works. Be happy.