# Running low disk space

Tags: 11.10, disk-usage

I am running Ubuntu 11.10.For past few days I am getting messages stating that running on low disk space.Can any one help me to free space?.

**df -h** shows this

http://paste.ubuntu.com/775964/

**sudo fdisk -l** shows this

http://paste.ubuntu.com/775963/

I am having Windows 7 as the other OS.

**NOTE: I am novice in Linux.**

Answer (score 1):

I see from your `sudo fdisk -l` output that you have 12 partitions (several of which are labeled `Linux swap / Solaris`, where you should only have one AFAIK), and your Linux partition (`sda11`) is only 4.3GB big, and using 3.4GB of that space. I don't think you allocated enough space for Ubuntu during setup, unless that's incorrect and something else is wrong.

You may want to consider getting rid of some of your other partitions, particularly your extra swap partitions, to make room so you can resize your Linux partition. This can be done by using a program like GParted (be sure to back up any data first; see [Resize partition without affecting other OSes in dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/58529/18612) for details). That, or get a larger/additional hard drive.

Comment: Hi sorry i mixed up the paste bin URLs so it might have created confusion.Please check the update.

Comment: @upsla Thanks for letting me know! Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

All though I agree with WarriorIng64, in the way, that 4.3G is really not that much space for a whole OS, you could try using `du` to find what is eating up your disk space.

`du -as --max-depth=N /` gives you a listing of the disk usage of all folders from your filesystem root to depth N.

As I see you have quite a few platters, I might suggest to you to move some folders (for example your home folder) to a different disk. This can be done quite simply via an [fstab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) entry.

Comment: the command you mentioned does not seem to work.