# Ubuntu 20.04 system has low disk space on /var and doesnt boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation, 20.04, disk-usage

I installed my Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday using the directions in internet. I just installed some IDEs and Android Studio etc to my computer (nothing very large) from Software Center, and now the system is telling me that I have low disk space on `/var`.

I gave lots of space for Ubuntu when partitioning; about 70 GB of my SSD.I read some old questions but can't find a solution.

Because of this, my computer is not booting. My `/var` partition looks 95% to 100% full.

I already tried clean and autoremove codes.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I also don't understand software store where to install programs directory...

Here is my `df` output

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8147072       0   8147072   0% /dev
tmpfs            1635040    2164   1632876   1% /run
/dev/sda6       19091540 6409132  11689540  36% /
tmpfs            8175192  262896   7912296   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8175192       0   8175192   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5         968312  140208    761700  16% /boot
/dev/sda9       68524344  901060  64099344   2% /home
/dev/sda2          98304   33385     64919  34% /boot/efi
/dev/sda8        3779640 3559292      8636 100% /var
/dev/loop0        146304  146304         0 100% /snap/code/33
/dev/loop2         31104   31104         0 100% /snap/snapd/7777
/dev/loop1         96256   96256         0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop3         56320   56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop4         99456   99456         0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop6        246656  246656         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
/dev/loop5         56320   56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop7         27776   27776         0 100% /snap/snapd/7264
/dev/loop8         63616   63616         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop9        597376  597376         0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/232
/dev/loop10        51072   51072         0 100% /snap/snap-store/433
/dev/loop11        51072   51072         0 100% /snap/snap-store/454
/dev/loop12       261760  261760         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
tmpfs            1635036      20   1635016   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs            1635036      28   1635008   1% /run/user/1000
```

Thank your for any help.

Comment: Why is /var (and /boot) on a separate partition anyway?

Comment: Looks like you made a classic Windows-power-user mistake and over-partitioned. Perhaps some of your early assumptions didn't work out. It happens.. Your're stuck with it until you can back up your data -- re-partitioning risks data loss. You cannot use partitioning tools on mounted partitions, including your root (/) partition, so you must boot from a LiveUSB to re-partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize partition without affecting other OSes in dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58529/resize-partition-without-affecting-other-oses-in-dual-boot)

Comment: @user535733 how should I divide partitions ?

Comment: Well, you seemingly made all these decisions before. Revisit your assumptions based upon what you have learned, and go through that decision-making process again. The best partitioning scheme is one that YOU understand and can maintain. Personally, I find the Ubuntu Installer default settings to be quite sane and sensible, and I usually recommend sticking close to those for new users who lack a preference.

Comment: @user535733 I just installaed my computer no worry to lose data.So I will reinstall dual boot linux for recommended settings.Thx for the answers..